# Qt error in .obj file: unresolved externals

Tags: qt, opengl, openmesh

So I have changed the following lines:

```
LIBS += \
    /usr/local/lib/libOpenMeshCore.so  \
    /usr/local/lib/libOpenMeshTools.so

LIBS += \
    -lglut -lGLU
```

to:

```
LIBS += \
    -lglut32 -lOpenMeshCored -lOpenMeshToolsd
```

and then I encounter these error:

```
QGLViewerWidget.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glutWireTeapot referenced in function "protected: virtual void __cdecl QGLViewerWidget::draw_scene(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)"

QGLViewerWidget.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glutSolidTeapot referenced in function "protected: virtual void __cdecl QGLViewerWidget::draw_scene(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)"

meshviewer.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___glutInitWithExit referenced in function glutInit_ATEXIT_HACK
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your OpenMesh library is 64-bit and you are trying to link it with a 32-bit glut library, which is not possible. You have two options:

1. Don't use glut32, and use 64-bit glut library.
2. If you need a 32-bit binary, change all your other libs to 32-bit version as well. And to run the 32-bit application on Linux (which seems you're on), you may need to add `i386` architecture (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454253/how-to-run-32-bit-app-in-ubuntu-64-bit) for more info).

Comment: do you have site where I can download glut64, been searching for that and also for glu. And by the way, I've been using the glut32 in my other program and it works well. But as you mentioned, may be it has a compatibility problem with the openmesh library. And also, I'm using windows not linux.

Comment: @elladeguzman There are a few places that people have compiled 64-bit glut for windows, such as [here](http://hoteldomenicoflorio.com/card/glut64.php). However, glut license doesn't allow recompiling, which makes it unavailable. You may have luck using [freeglut](https://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/software/freeglut-devel/), but my suggestion is using a recent version of qt which I believe wouldn't have glut dependency.